# Firebase data structure for chat

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to build an app for employers to chat with employees.

So I have employers, employees and messages.

I did it with `$firebaseArray` and childs:

```
recipient > sender > messages
```

I want to add sender data such as profile images and last message, I'm not how to do it.

```
- employer_1
    - employee_1
       - SKLDJLKDksdklJS
              - content: "Hello"
              - timestamp: 129081021
```

Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: do you have the employer and employee information like profile images, details in the same tree or at a different location?

Comment: it's on a different sql database so i am wondering where i can put the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have issues of showing only latest messages or newer messages since any get on employer_1 -> employee_1 will load all messages.

Another alternate might be to have a structure like this:

```
{
"users":{
  "employer_1":{
     "profile-image":"<url>",
     "last-message":"SKLDJLKDksdklJS",
     ...
     },
   "employee_1"{
       "profile-image":"<url>",
       "user-chat-list":{
          "employer_1":{
              "last-message":"SKLDJLKDksdklJS",
              "message-list":{
                  "SKLDJLKDksdklJS" : 129081021,
                  "ASDCJLKDksdklJS" : 129081021
              }
          }
       }  
   }
 },
 "messages":{
    "SKLDJLKDksdklJS":{
       "content": "Hello",
       "sender":"employer_1",
       "timestamp": 129081021
      }
 }
}
```

you won't need to fetch all the messages with content for a chat list.

Comment: is this way using $firebaseObject instead of $firebaseArray? just making sure. i'm new to this, thanks

Comment: what client library are you using?  you could get by using `var db = firebase.database();` and then use `db.ref().update(updates)` to update any part of your firebase database

Comment: ah, never used that myself :) but looking at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653704/unable-to-get-my-data-from-firebaseobject-using-angularfire-in-a-controller-vi) my guess would be to continue using firebaseArray for any collection